# How to do a redirect in tomcat from `/old` to a webapp `/new` without having a webapp `/old` deployed?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, redirect

We gradually moved from an old webapp to a new one.

Until now, both were deployed: `/old` and `/new`.

Now, the new one is fully functioning and we'd like to completely delete the old one. The problem is that users might have saved bookmarks to the old webapp. Every relative path in `/old/whatever` is supported by `/new/whatever`.

**How do I do the redirect without deploying an `/old` webapp?** Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this stuff with Apache and ProxyPass

```
ProxyPass        /old/ /new/
ProxyPassReverse /old/ /new/
```

Answer (score 0):

In situations like these you have 3 choices:

1. Deploy a new `/old` app with redirects in place
2. Implement redirect rules on your Web server (apache,nginx)
3. Implement redirect rules on your CDN

As you mentioned don't want to redeploy a new web application under `/old` so your best choice would be to implement redirect rules either in your web server or CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tomcat rewrite](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html). It works like Apache HTTP. Look also for [host confige](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html)